# Custom fonts size in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How to find String size for custom fonts like calibri and midnightkernboy fonts in IPhone code

I am using FontLabel code

Comment: Not clear, can u be a little more specific about ur doubt??

Answer (score 1):

From what little I can understand from your question I give you this:

```
NSString measureString = @"A string to measure";
CGSize stringSize = [measureString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Calibri" size:12]];
```

Make sure you spell the font name correctly.